# Google Mobile Vision Barcode location on screen

Tags: java, android, qr-code, barcode, google-vision

I am writing an AR Android application in which I scan QR codes (using the **Google Mobile Vision Barcode API**) as a trigger and then render objects into the camera view.

As there may be more than one QR code at the same time, I want to access the location of each code on the screen, so that the objects will be rendered on top of each code. At the moment - if there are two QR codes being detected by the camera - the objects will be placed at the exact same position in 3D space.

*Example:*

> There are two QR codes being detected by the camera, one on the left
> and one on the right of my camera view. Right now, both objects would
> be rendered in the center of my camera view, as this is the default
> value of my app.
>
> I want the object related with the left code to
> appear on the left and the object related with the right code to
> appear on the right.

I have tried calling `Barcode.getBoundingBox().exactCenterX()` and `[...].exactCenterY()` to get a rough value of the code's location, but it does not work out well. Unfortunately I can't find a more suitable method in the documentation.

I can't be the only one who needs the code's location on the screen. How did you guys do that?

Thanks a lot.